# Microsoft SQL Server 2012: How to Insert record into relational tables

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2012

is there a way to insert a record into relational tables and not to run query for each table?

I need to insert a new log: l_WinUser, l_Status, t_StartTime, t_StartDate where username = username, g_Exe = g_Exe

And if so is there a way in .NET to get the inserted record ID? Currently I am executing another query to retrieve the inserted log (works fine):

```
SELECT TOP (1) Logs.l_LogID 
FROM Logs 
INNER JOIN Game ON Logs.g_GameID = Game.g_GameID 
INNER JOIN Member ON Logs.m_MemberID = Member.m_MemberID 
WHERE (Game.g_Exe = @exe) 
AND (Member.m_Username = @username) 
AND (Logs.l_WinUser = @winUser)
ORDER BY Logs.l_LogID DESC
```

Here's the ERD:

[image: erd]

Thank you so much.

Comment: To get the latest inserted value of an `IDENTITY` column, use the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "relational table"? Every table in a relational database is "relational" (that's why it's called a relational database)

Comment: As @horse says, every table in an RDBMS is "relational". Some people even call tables "relations". So, please don't use that term ("relational"). @Dav, I guess you mean a "join" or ["junction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) or "many-to-many" table like the `Logs` you have (which models a many-to-many-to-many relationship)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a VIEW, an INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger and run one `INSERT`-Statement against it.

```
create View View_Logs 
as
select l_WinUser, 
       l_Status, 
       t_StartTime, 
       1t_StartDate,
       username,
       g_Exe
FROM Logs 
INNER JOIN Game ON Logs.g_GameID = Game.g_GameID 
INNER JOIN Member ON Logs.m_MemberID = Member.m_MemberID
```

Now you insert your new entry like this

```
insert into View_logs
  (l_WinUser,l_status, lt_StartDate,username,g_exe)
values
  ('Foo', 1, GetDate(),'BarUser','SomeEXE')
```

You will get the new `l_LogID` using

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

NOTE: In the first attempt I wrote that an INSERT against a view would also insert/update related tables, which is not true. So I corrected this answer.

And here's the trigger (untested):

```
create trigger YourTriggerName on View_ogs
for instead of insert 
as
declare @GameID int, @MemberID int, @timeKey int

select @GameID=g_GameID from Game g join inserted i on g.g_Exe = i.g_exe
if @GameID is null begin
  insert into Game (g_exe) select g_exe from Inserted
  select @GameID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  end

select @MemberID=m.m_memberID from Member m join inserted i on m_username = i.username
if @MemberID is null begin
  insert into Member (m_username) select username from Inserted
  select @MemberID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  end

select @timeKey=t.t_timeKey 
from Time_Date t 
     join inserted i 
       on t.t_StartTime=i.t_StartTime 
      and t.t_StartDate = t_StartDate

if @timeKey is null begin
  insert into Time_Date (t_StartTime, t_StartDate) select t_StartTime, t_StartDate from Inserted
  select @timeKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  end

set nocount off
insert into Logs
  (l_WinUser, l_Status, m_MemberID, g_GameID, t_TimeKey)
  select l_WinUser, l_Status, @MemberID, @GameID, @timekey)
```

Comment: Oh, I thought it would work. Sorry, I will correct my attempt.

Comment: You can't update multiple tables with one statement, in SQL-Server. Even if a View is updatable.

Comment: With a trigger, you can. Please read the first sentence and the NOTE at the end.

Comment: Of course you can but triggers are not statements. Why don't you provide the `INSTEAD OF` trigger you mention? You may get a few upvotes that way :)

Comment: @alzaimar I need to create this trigger and view then apply the insert?

Comment: Yes. First create the view and then the trigger. As mentioned, it is untested. If you want to update, you will also have to provide another trigger. The same applies to `DELETE`.